# Eclipse JDK 7 Start Failure

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, classpath

When I try to use the eclipse.exe file to start the eclipse it fails. This issue started occuring after I installed JDK 7 on my system .

When I use the command line paramater

> ```
> eclipse -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin"
> ```

eclipse starts just fine.  I am assuming it is something related to the JVM which has caused the issue.

Meanwhile when I try to check java version I get the following error:

> C:\Test>java -version 
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM

Not sure if the two are related.

Comment: Since `java -version` gives an error, try reinstalling Java 7.

Comment: Apologies, the issue is sorted out now. JDK path needs to be set correctly in the PATH variable. Once that is done the same can be checked by `code` C:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode, sharing)`code`

Comment: @Nivas, I highly doubt that OP needs to go through the trouble of reinstalling Java 7...just need to configure the environment variables correctly (as long as OP still has the Java 7 download).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java -version` failing indicates to me that you probably need to configure the OS environment variables,

- `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06`
- `Path=...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`